# VB: Transfering all text from one listbox to another

Tags: vb.net

Thanks for reading guys first of all. Secondly I'd like button1 to transfer all text from listbox1 to listbox2. So when button1 is clicked, all items in listbox1 transfers to listbox2. Here is what I have, thanks again:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

   ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItems)

End Sub
```

Using VB2012

Comment: The question says "all items" but the code you show refers to `SelectedItems`. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

To copy all items from one listbox to another (ListBox1 -> ListBox2):

```
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items)
```

Comment: @user3387807: Please accept and upvote the answers you find useful.

Comment: @user3387807: Not a problem. Please accept whichever answer you find most useful. This is to let other members knows problem has been resolved and does not require attention. You can upvote as many answers as you want when you earn enough reputation.

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work when you want to only transfer selected items... items and SelectedItems are 2 different types and cannot be casted as they do inherit from the same class.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()  //This is to avoid duplication if button was clicked more than once

     For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You traverse on the 1st `Listbox` selected items and add each item in your 2nd `ListBox`, like

```
For Each Item As String In ListBox1.SelectedItems
  ListBox2.Items.Add(Item)
Next
```